# How to configure SSH fallback keys for regex

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-config

I'm trying to configure my SSH config file to try several different keys and users for a domain. I was using a function in my dotfiles to do this originally but it's unwieldy, slow, and ugly.

My company has multiple servers with different private keys and users for SSH login. There are a plethora of hostnames, but the domain is always the same.

I could look up in our master record what key/username pair I need, but that's no fun.

This is part of my SSH config file:

```
 Host *.companydomain.net
     User ubuntu
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_a.pem

 Host *.companydomain.net
     User ubuntu
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_b

 Host *.companydomain.net
     User anotheruser
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_c
```

So right now it seems like the first entry (using `key_a.pem`) is tried, then it fails and doesn't fall through. Ideally, I'd like this to fall through and try each of the three combinations until a log in succeeds.

I am running macOS running OpenSSH_7.6p1.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure those aren’t regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

The manual says you can use multiple `IdentityFile` directives, and all listed files will be used, so the first two entries could be combined to

```
Host *.companydomain.net
    User ubuntu
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_a.pem
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_b
```

But I don't think you can try multiple user names with one `ssh` invocation (or one SSH connection), so for that you might need to script it anyway.

If you put the third `IdentityFile` along with the others, the script doesn't need to be very long, I think something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/sh
for user in ubuntu anotheruser; do
    ssh -l "$user" "$@" && break;
done
```

(Take the `User` directive off from the configuration file in this case.)